# Tomcat 7.0.47 will not launch

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, classpath, liferay-6

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.AccessLogAdapter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityClassLoad.loadCorePackage(SecurityClassLoad.java:56)
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityClassLoad.securityClassLoad(SecurityClassLoad.java:40)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:426)
```

I don't understand why tomcat will not launch. I'm still configuring it, but I have catalina.jar inside $TOMCAT_HOME/lib. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention I am running on RHL

UPDATE: Okay so after fiddling with catalina.properties and catalina.sh for the past few days, I think I may have discovered the source of the issue. I think my class path is set up correctly, so I went through and double checked the libraries that they were pointed towards and I saw that the catalina.jar file was corrupted. I changed it out and now I'm getting the following message as opposed to the one above:

```
 catalina
        at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityClassLoad.securityClassLoad(SecurityClassLoad.java:40)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:426)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.AsyncContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 15 more
```

This class also resides within the catalina.jar file. What is the deal here! Could all of my .jar files be corrupted?

Comment: How did you start the tomcat java process?

Comment: sh $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh jpda start

tail -f $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out

Comment: You'll have to check your `catalina.sh` file and the related shell scripts to see if the `java` command is launched with the appropriate classpath.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I'm not sure where this change needs to be made

Comment: I don't know exactly where in the file it's done, but a variable is constructed that holds the application classpath to use when executing the `java` application launcher. You need to check if it's being built correctly with `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`.

Comment: I have all of my environment variables setup properly, that's the frustrating thing.

Comment: I've ran a script that exports all of the proper environment variables

    export LIFERAY_HOME=/dir/dir2/liferay-portal-6.2.0
    export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23
    export TOMCAT_HOME=${LIFERAY_HOME}/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
    export CATALINA_BASE=${TOMCAT_HOME}
    export CATALINA_HOME=${TOMCAT_HOME}
    export CATALINA_TEMPDIR=${TOMCAT_HOME}/temp

These are all referenced in catalina.sh, but for some reason Tomcat is not able to locate them.

Comment: I've ran a script that exports all of the proper environment variables 
export LIFERAY_HOME=/dir/dir2/liferay-portal-6.2.0 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_23 
export TOMCAT_HOME=${LIFERAY_HOME}/apache-tomcat-7.0.47 
export CATALINA_BASE=${TOMCAT_HOME} 
export CATALINA_HOME=${TOMCAT_HOME} export CATALINA_TEMPDIR=${TOMCAT_HOME}/temp These are all referenced in catalina.sh, but for some reason Tomcat is not able to locate them.